# Extern "C" and C++ structure and typedef

Tags: c++, c, pointers, struct

I have started using C++ for win32. As we know C++ struct is same as class but default public member etc... Now I want is simple C struct that has no default constructor or copy or move operation or any other magic. Because I want to store it in file also perform memcpy, use as BYTE array etc... So I thought of defining it in header with #ifdef __cplusplus as follow.

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

typedef struct PersonTag 
{
    int ID;
    char Name[200];

} Person, *PPerson;

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

But this only prevent name mangling for function. But struct still compile as cpp struct if in cpp file or as C struct if in C file. I tested it by including header in cpp file and in C file. Both compiles well but if I add constructor in struct body as following.

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

typedef struct PersonTag 
{
    PersonTag();
    int ID;
    char Name[200];

} Person, *PPerson;

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

C++ compile it without err but C fails as it should be. Does that means that even if I include struct definition inside #ifdef __cplusplus it will still compile as C++ struct with all copy and move magic with it ?
I was thinking that by defining struct in side ' extern "C" ' will also produce err in cpp file if struct has c++ style constructor etc...
So my question is, Is there a way to tell c++ compiler(vc++) to consider and compile it as like it is pure C struct, no default constructor, no default destructor, move or copy like thing or anything else.

My second question is about typdefing cpp function pointer and passing this function pointer to C function which may call it back.
I am using C lib (sqlite3) and passing callback fun. Now if I typedef function pointer in cpp file by following way.

```
typedef int (*SQL_CALLBACK_FUN)(void* NotUsed, int argc, char** argv, char** azColName);
```

in Cpp file the function might be like

```
int Callback_GetAllPerson(void* NotUsed, int argc, char** argv, char** azColName);
```

and than the function pointer be

```
SQL_CALLBACK_FUN sql_callback_fun = Callback_GetAllPerson;
```

Now I am going to pass this "sql_callback_fun" function pointer to C lib function (sqlite3_exec).
My question is, here I typdef function pointer in CPP also the callback function will compile as cpp. now I am passing it to C lib as pointer and the C lib function will call back this cpp function via pointer.

Is there any runtime err I might face? or the function pointer (typdef) is same for both cpp and c. regardless of name mangling things?

Comment: I suggest treating copy and move less as "magic" and read a bit more on them. For a simple aggregate such as you show, those "magic" operations are a bitwise copy. **Exactly** like C would handle it.

Comment: And the overall size of the C++ structure will be the same as for the plain C structure. IIRC, even the memory layout will be the same, so you can read/write to/from binary files across C and C++ programs. (I think.)

Comment: Don't ask two unrelated question in one post. Separate them, please.

Comment: What is the difference between a C struct and a CPP struct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *But struct still compile as cpp struct if in cpp file or as C struct if in C file*

You can't compile some code as C using a C++ compiler. A C++ compiler compiles *everything* as C++ code.

Fortunately the C++ language guarantees that "standard-layout" classes are layout-compatible with C. So you have nothing to worry about, your struct will be identical when compiled as C or C++. The `extern "C"` only affects name mangling (adds a leading underscope, for example), so that identifiers compiled as C++ can be "found" by C code during linking.

Obviously you should not add C++ features like a constructor, if the struct is to be compiled as C as well as C++.

For free function pointers, make sure to use `extern "C"` to enforce [C language linkage](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/language_linkage).

So your very first code fragment looks fine.

Answer (score 1):

`extern "C"` has nothing to do with the struct. But you are on the right track though, you just need to `#ifdef` the constructor:

```
/* Compiles as both C++ and C */
struct Person {
    int ID;
    char Name[200];
#ifdef __cplusplus
    Person() : ID(0), Name("") {}
#endif
};

typedef struct Person Person, *PPerson;
```

If you really don't want to have access to the constructors generated by the compiler, you can `delete` them:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
Person() = delete;
Person(const Person&) = delete;
Person(Person&&) = delete;
#endif
```

Compiling the following code to test proves that these structures have identical sizes:

```
int main () {
    printf("Person is %d bytes\n", sizeof(Person));
}
```

output:

```
$ g++ -o foo_cpp foo.c
$ ./foo_cpp
Person is 204 bytes
$ gcc -o foo_c foo.c
$ ./foo_c
Person is 204 bytes
```

As for your second question: yes, passing a C++ function pointer will work as expected. Symbol mangling and conversion to an address is handled by the C++ compiler.

Comment: I did not downvote, but I think it is this: You are not providing a solution for the OP's question, how to prohibit the creation of C++'s class methods.

Comment: Thanks, I added something about that. Although I disagree with the motivations given ;)

Comment: @Botje I also did not downvote. But I think you don't understand first part my question clearly. I already know how to delete constructor or prevent all default move and copy operation. The question is about C and C++ structure compatibility, Memory model. If I write the structure in file using C. Than, will I get back the same memory model in C++? If not how to make it compatible. I thought c++ auto generate default constructor and other things. Because of that structure size would be different than C. So I want compatibility using compiler directives if needed and possible.

Comment: No, the size of the struct will be identical between C and C++. The constructors might be *declared* inside the `struct` code, but that does not mean they take up any space at runtime. Only `virtual` methods make the struct size different, since that *does* require the compiler to insert a vtable pointer. See my edit for proof.

Comment: @vkchavda Botje is correct, the member functions (including constructors and destructors) don't make any changes to the memory layout, except for the first function declared virtual.  Those functions will be mapped to the class at compile time so they don't need run time support.

Answer (score 1):

> But this only prevent name mangling for function. But struct still compile as cpp struct if in cpp file or as C struct if in C file.

This is actually a good thing. This allows you to use the struct in both languages.

> I was thinking that by defining struct in side ' extern "C" ' will also produce err in cpp file if struct has c++ style constructor etc

You were thinking wrong. It only affects name mangling.

> Is there a way to tell c++ compiler(vc++) to consider and compile it as like it is pure C struct

No. C++ compiler compiles C++; C compiler compiles C.

If you want a struct definition to be compatible in both languages, then you must write it in common subset of both languages.

---

> Is there any runtime err I might face [with callbacks]?

Typical potential problem is that if the callback throws, then things blow up because the calling C code won't deal with exceptions. You must make sure that the callback doesn't throw.

Answer (score 0):

For a simple struct with no class members, the default constructor and destructor will be empty functions.  No members will be initialized, and no members will be destroyed.  A good optimizer will completely eliminate the calls to those empty functions, leaving you with the same generated code under both C and C++.

Similarly with the default copy constructor and copy operator, they will do a simple bit-wise copy of the entire struct.  Same operation regardless of whether it's C or C++.

Since C can't do move operations, no need to even think about it.

In short, there's nothing to worry about.  Consider that Microsoft defines the entire Windows API with C structures, but people call it from C++ every day.